# How can I delete marks in Kile/Kate in vim-mode?

Tags: vim, vi, kate, kile

When setting marks in Kile’s/Kate’s vim-mode via `m.` the line will be highlighted. This can be annoying and the attempt to remove the mark via `:delmarks` fails with `unknown command: “delmarks”`.

**Is it possible to remove marks in Kate’s vi editor?** How if so?

Answer (score 0):

At least it is possible to remove bookmarks via gui in kile: The bookmarks menu provides this action as well as the context menu.